# Writing C function parameter types after name list, and no type for some parameters

Tags: c, parameters, coding-style, legacy

I've read some, to me, peculiar C-code while studying some examples in the book The Unix Programming Environment (1983).

As a curiosity I wanted to find out more about the, let's call it "style". The point of interest here is the line just below `int main(argc, argv)`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(argc, argv)
     char *argv[];
{
    printf("%s\n", argv[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

In my investigation I've found that compiling the above code with the flags `-Wall -pedantic -ansi` works without any warnings, and replacing `-ansi` with the more recent `-std=c99` (or `c11`, with `gcc` and `cc`) only warns about `argc` defaulting to `int`.

I perused the old C89 standard trying to find references to this particular way of writing
but didn't find anything on my own so I defer to the greater knowledge of the collective.

Hence the question, from when does this esoteric writing stem and possibly why is it still allowed (legacy reasons?)

Comment: This is called "K&R" style and was the defacto standard set by the first implementations of C and documented in the first edition of the Kernighan and Ritchie book. A declaration that didn't include a type would default to `int`, and arguments were typed in the style you give.  There were no function prototypes, just function declarations. The C89 standard added protoypes, but also supported K&R style as valid for legacy reasons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The old way to do things was to have functions without prototypes.  Functions return `int` by default, and since the function parameter types are unknown at the call site, you better get it right.  This frees you from having to maintain header files, but for various reasons, it is no longer recommended.

```
// In func.c

// Default to int return
func(x, y)
    int x;
    int y;
{
    return x + y;
}

// In main.c

main(argc, argv)
    int argc;
    char **argv;
{
    int result = func(2, 3);
}
```

This causes problems if you get the function parameter types wrong.

```
int result = func(2.0, 3,0); // Wrong, but no compiler error or warning
```

It was normal to call functions without including the relevant header file.  But you need to declare the function return type.

```
// This is NOT a function prototype, it just declares the return type.
double sin();

double one = sin(3.14); // Correct
double zero = sin(0); // WRONG
double zero = sin(0.0); // Correct
```

Old style functions are still allowed by the standard, except the default return type is gone.  This allows you to compile old programs.  For new programs, the `-Wmissing-prototypes` option in GCC helps you to avoid using the old style by accident.

```
int func(); // Old-style, can take any number of arguments.
int func(void); // New-style, takes no arguments, is a function prototype.
```

Answer (score 3):

This is good old fashioned [K&R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) C.

Everything is by default an integer, and you define the actual types of parameters in functions, not in the prototype, but in a separate declaration list. It made writing integer-only code easier, but made debugging function calls a nightmare.

Here's a function written in both styles.

```
int myFunc(const char *from, char *to, int len); // Ah that feels right, doesn't it

int myFunc(const char *from, char *to, int len){} // And here's the definition

myKRFunc(); /* Okay, that's a declaration */

myKRFunc(from, to, len) /* Yep, you just write the parameter names here */
    char *from, *to;    /* And you can write normal declarations, len defaults to an int */
{}
```

I wanted to explain why debugging function calls without prototypes was harder, but Dietrich covers it in his answer well.

Answer (score 2):

This is the original K&R style C. It's still legal, because why not? Backwards compatibility lets people move forward in small steps. That's the pain of any popular evolving system.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on the old "standard", so I wouldn't worry too much about it. I definitely don't recommend programming in that style, but it's useful to know it exists in case you encounter more legacy code.

Comment: It's not based on any "old standard". C didn't **have** a standard in 1983.

Comment: I put "standard" in quotes :)